# HTML: Make a column in the middle

Tags: html, css

I want to make a Website with a background that is fixed (i alredy have that) and in front of the background in the middle is my stuff, like this site: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/?  I searched the whole internet but I can't find anything. and I already searched in the source. Can someone help me? sry for my bad english, I am swiss. Pleas feel free to correct me.

Comment: That's called a grid layout, check out http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/ , then visit the homepage and download the theme , read the documentation first good luck

Answer (score 1):

what your are looking for is setting a fixed width of your main content, and then set an auto margin for left and right so that it is centered.

```
.content {
    width:600px; //set your desire width here
    background-color:#ffffaa; // color is just there to visualize
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

in your HTML:

```
<body>
  <!-- header -->

  <!-- main content -->
  <div class="content">
     This is the main content box
  </div>

  <!-- footer -->

</body>
```

Hope this would help.
regs,
Yann

Comment: To support Yann's answer, here is a [**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3naT/)